# Problems posting a comment as 'current_user' (Devise) in a micropost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is how I post a Micropost as `current_user` ([Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)):

**microposts_controller.rb:**

```
 def create
    @user = current_user
    @micropost = @user.microposts.new(params[:micropost])
    @micropost.save
    redirect_to @micropost
  end
```

This is how I post a comment in a micropost:

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to micropost_path(@micropost)
  end
```

Now I would like to post a comment as `current_user`

Any suggestions in order to accomplish this?

**microposts/show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@micropost, @micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

Not sure if you need to see this but here are the models:

**comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :micropost
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**micropost.rb**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :microposts
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: How are you setting the `user` attribute in a new comment? its not attr_accessiable

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Sorry, I changed that. Comments have an `user_id` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your comments_controller:

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  comment_attr = params[:comment].merge :user_id => current_user.id
  @comment = @micropost.comments.create(comment_attr)
  redirect_to micropost_path(@micropost)
end
```

Until now, I think your comments didn't have a user attached to them..

Edit - I changed :user to be :user_id. makes more sense, since we don't have a comment yet.

Comment: Thanks for helping but I get this: `database is locked. app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:22:in `create'. {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ciwlksY+xXnS6zW6xwAGayK3N/5lhRwTa1pa5x9SYOg=","comment"=>{"content"=>"ssadasd"},"commit"=>"Create Comment", "micropost_id"=>"3"}`